# Is there a way to penalize or assign cost to transferring edges when routing in pgrouting?

Tags: pgrouting, routing

I'm trying to create a routing app for bus routes. I got the network noded and they're all over the place as expected. Running `pgr_Dijkstra()` returns like 5 bus line, with 8 transfers on a trip.

The routing works but it should have been just 1 direct bus ride, not 8 transfers on 5 different bus lines over a distance of just about 2kilometers.

So, is there a way to prevent pgr_Dijkstra() from jumping around nodes/edges or is there another function I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You need to design a graph/network, that has high costs when changing bus lines.

You could create "transfer connections" (virtual edges) where transfers are possible, and you would assign high costs to these edges. If you use time as cost for example, you would apply a time penalty for traversing such a transfer edge, and that way you would make the algorithm avoid transfers.

Comment: Hi @dkastl, I don't think that creating virtual edges would work for my specific scenario because transfers are possible anywhere. Some lines (around 15) share the same road so I'm not sure how to route when a tiny zig or zag could add 5 meters to the agg_cost.